# Unable to delete data of flatpak - connection is closed error

Tags: debian, software-installation, error-handling, flatpak, uninstall

I was using KdenLive but I messed up some of the settings so I decided to do a fresh install. When I used the GUI to remove then reinstall, the settings were intact. Then I went to the terminal and ran this command:

```
flatpak uninstall --delete-data org.kde.kdenlive


        ID                             Branch        Op
 1. [-] org.kde.kdenlive               stable        r
 2. [-] org.kde.kdenlive.Locale        stable        r

Uninstall complete.
Delete data for org.kde.kdenlive? [y/n]: y
error: The connection is closed
```

As you can see the program is deleted but when I try to remove the data it spits out a `connection closed` error. What can I do to fully remove all data so that I start with default settings when I reinstall it later?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually purge your userdata. In the case of `KdenLive`, go to `~/.var/app/org.kde.kdenlive` and remove all the folders in it. Then launch KdenLive. It will crash. When you launch it again, it will ask whether you want to reset configurations. Click yes and KdenLive will automatically restore itself to its vanilla state.